# cant get jrumble to work -- causing other script to not function (conflicts)

Tags: jquery, html, animation, conflict

I'm trying to get jrumble to work. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKwum/

Here is my html:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jrumble.1.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mainNav').jrumble();
        $('#mainNav').hover(function () {
            $(this).trigger('startRumble');
        }, function () {
            $(this).trigger('stopRumble');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
    <!--START TOP -->
    <div id="top">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 div = "headers"></h1>   
    <!--START NAVIGATION -->
              <ul id="mainNav">
                <li><a href="#top"><img src="images/fork.png">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutPortfolio"><img src="images/spooon.png">My Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutMe"><img src="images/knife.png">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contactMe"><img src="images/rollingpin.png">Let's Talk!</a></li>
              </ul>  
        </div>  
    <!--END NAVIGATION -->          
            <img id="backgroundroll" class="clear" alt="" src="">
    </div>
    <!--END TOP -->
    <!--START Portfolio -->
    <div id="aboutPortfolio" class="clear">
        <div class ="wrap">
            <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <div id="works">
                <!--WORKBOX 1 START -->
                    <div class="workBox bordered">
                        <div class="inWrap">
                            <div class="imageBox">
                                <ul>
                                    <li title="screenshot1" style="display: block;">
                                        <a class="Screenshot" href="" rel=</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="discriptionsBox">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>Client: Development Group</strong>
                                        A small-business, start-up consulting firm.
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>Bootstrap Template</p>
                                    <p>Extras: Javascript</p>
                                    <p>CMS: PHPMYADMIN</p>
                                </div>
                                    <a class="workLink" href="http://www.mhd.org.pl"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <!--WORKBOX 2 START -->
                    <div class="workBox bordered">
                        <div class="inWrap">
                            <div class="imageBox">
                                <ul>
                                    <li title="screenshot1" style="display: block;">
                                        <a class="Screenshot" href="" rel=</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="discriptionsBox">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>Client:</strong>
                                        A custom designed blog for the purpose of writing about cinema.
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>How: Hand-coded based on custom specs by the client</p>
                                    <p>Extras: Jquery, Javascript plug in</p>
                                    <p>CMS: MYPHPADMIN</p>
                                </div>
                                    <a class="workLink" href="http://www.mhd.org.pl"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <!--WORKBOX 3 START -->
                     <div class="workBox bordered">
                        <div class="inWrap">
                            <div class="imageBox">
                                <ul>
                                    <li title="screenshot1" style="display: block;">
                                        <a class="Screenshot" href="" rel=</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="discriptionsBox">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>Client:</strong>
                                        Discription here.
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>.</p>
                                    <p> </p>
                                    <p>.</p>
                                </div>
                                    <a class="workLink" href="http://www.mhd.org.pl"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <!--END PORTFOLIO -->
    <!--START ABOUT ME --> 
    <div id ="aboutMe" class="clear">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>About me</h2>
                <div id="aboutDescription">
                    <p>.</p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p</p>
                    <p> <a href="http://" rel="follow">More</a></p>
                    <p class="bigger">.</p> 
                        <img id="photo" alt="" src="http://www.">
                    <div id="aboutLinks">  
                      <h3></h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a></a></li>
                            <li><a></a></li>
                            <li><a></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>    
                </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <!--END ABOUT ME -->    
    <!--START CONTACT ME -->    
    <div id = "contactMe">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
                <div id="contactDescription">
                    <p>.</p>
                    <div id ="contactForm">
                    </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <!--END CONTACT ME -->
    <!--START FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer" class="wrap">
        <img alt="" src="">
            <p>
                Copyright © 2013 Firm Technology Solutions, LLC.
                    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Valid HTML 4.01 strict</a>
                        &
                            <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a>
            </p>
    </div>
    <!--END FOOTER -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Additionally I'm having a problem with the other script which is just a smooth-scroll plug in. It was working fine until I attempted to add this one in. I added no-conflicts + wrapping in doc.ready() brackets.

Could use some help from a more jquery savvy individual thanks!

p.s i know it won't work with ab/fixed divs without being inside a wrapper. Its relative.

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery in no conflict mode, you should use the "jQuery" prefix instead of "$".  Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#mainNav').jrumble();
    jQuery('#mainNav').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).trigger('startRumble');
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).trigger('stopRumble');
    });
});
```

EDIT: Add a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKwum/1/)

Comment: I modified your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKwum/1/) to show you a working example.  Your jsFiddle did not include the jrumble library.  I also added the jQuery.noConflict() call so that it more closely follows your real code.